# Is it possible to set the volume slider to a fixed interval in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

When I press fn+vol down on my keyboard, windows does it in increments of 2

This would be great, because I can adjust it from say, 30, to 10, or exactly what I want by pressing it repeatedly.

However for some ludicrous reason, when pressing volume down repeatedly, it goes 30, 28, 26, 24, 22, 20, 18, 8, 2, 0

This is utterly maddening. It does not do this for volume up, just volume down.

Is there a registry key or similar that will disable this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script. You can fiddle around with the SoundSet systemcalls and bind them to your keyboard volume keys, which should bypass the weird incrementation you're seeing

```
~Volume_Up::SoundSet, +2
~Volume_Down::SoundSet, -2
```